# Struts2: How to set a specific rendering for one of my Radio buttons label?

Tags: html, struts2, radio-button, label, tooltip

In my web page, i need to display a list of several choice through radio buttons. And for one of these choice, the label is completed with an icon that could display a tooltip when the mouse is over it.

The html rendering is as below:

```
<label for="12">Available on.. <a href="#" class="pictos picto-help" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" rel="tooltip"><i class="icon-help" title="help" data-icon="&#xe602;"></i></a></label>
```

As you can see, the label contains a link and an iconic font. I need to put this link for this specific radio button but i don't know how is it possible when i use the struts2 radio tag to display the list of radio buttons.

My Radio tag is :

```
<s:radio name="filter" list="filterList" listKey="id" listValue="label" value="%{#attr['filter']}" />
```

The html rendering is classic:

```
<input id="filter0" type="radio" value="0" name="filter">
<label for="filter0">Tout</label>
```

And as i said before, i need to add a link in the label tag or juste after...

How is it possible ?

Comment: Use `<s:iterator>` and `<input>` tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<s:iterator value="filterList" var="a" status="s">
    <input type="radio" name="filter" title="${a.label}" value="${a.id}" id="filter${a.id}"/>
    <label for="filter${a.id}">${a.label}<a href="#" class="pictos picto-help" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" rel="tooltip"><i class="icon-help" title="help" data-icon="&#xe602;"></i></a></label>
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: Thanks, i'll try this with also a condition like `<s:if test="%{#s.count==2}">` to add the tooltip and its label to the specific label and input radio !